# Plot.ly dash-daq BooleanSwitch

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I have a layout that inclueds a `BooleanSwitch` from [dash-daq](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq). It works well but I want to change its color.

```
daq.BooleanSwitch(
  id='select',
  on=True,
)
```

In this aswer I found how to syle a slider 
[plot.ly(dash_core_components) slider color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943464/plot-lydash-core-components-slider-color-change) but I can not find the appropriate styling for das-daq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Dash DAQ boolean switch documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq/booleanswitch)

```
daq.BooleanSwitch(
  id='select',
  on=True,
  color="#9B51E0",
)
```

Comment: Oh. Almost too easy. I guess that the styling options for the slider got me confused. Many thanks.

Comment: Anytime Rudertier. Dash isn't always so straightforward